# sharepoint 2013 change existing publishing page page layout in CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I need to use CSOM to change the page layout of an existing publishing page in a publishing web. I saw there is CSOM object PublishingWeb, but it is lacking method for getting the publishing page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though in SharePoint 2013 CSOM new [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing(v=office.15).aspx) was introduced, it is still relatively limited API compared to SSOM counterpart. For example, CSOM [PublishingPage class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing.publishingpage(v=office.15).aspx) does not expose `Layout` property like SSOM `PublishingPage` [does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingpage.layout(v=office.14).aspx).

### How to set Page Layout for a publishing page using SharePoint CSOM

The following example allows to set page layout using CSOM in SharePoint 2010/2013:

```
pageItem["PublishingPageLayout"] = new FieldUrlValue() { Url = "<page layout server relative url>", Description = "<page layout name>" };
```

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to set `Blank Web Part page` page layout for a page:

```
var pagesList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
var pageItem = pagesList.GetItemById(listItemId);
pageItem["PublishingPageLayout"] = new FieldUrlValue() { Url = "/_catalogs/masterpage/BlankWebPartPage.aspx", Description = "Blank Web Part page" };
pageItem.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

### How to set Content Type for a List Item

In order to set Content Type for a List Item, the Content Type have to be available in a List. The below method is intended for that purpose:

```
public static void SetListItemContentType(ListItem item, ContentType contentType)
{
    var ctx = item.Context;
    //1. Ensure Content Type is available in List
    var list = item.ParentList;
    var result = ctx.LoadQuery(list.ContentTypes.Where(ct => ct.Name == contentType.Name));
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    var listContentType = result.FirstOrDefault();
    if (listContentType == null)
    {
        list.ContentTypes.AddExistingContentType(contentType);
        list.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    //2. Set Content Type for List Item 
    item["ContentTypeId"] = contentType.Id;
    item.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Usage

```
 var result = ctx.LoadQuery(ctx.Site.RootWeb.AvailableContentTypes.Where(ct => ct.Name == "Contoso Article Page"));
 ctx.ExecuteQuery();
 var pageContentType = result.FirstOrDefault();

 var pagesList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
 var pageItem = pagesList.GetItemById(7);
 SetListItemContentType(pageItem, pageContentType);
```

Comment: I tried this, the Page layout is changed to our custom layout, however the content type is still the OOB one, I tried to update the "ContentTypeId" field but failed.

Comment: It occurs since custom Content Type have to be added into List fist. The answer has been updated, see the section: How to set Content Type for a List Item

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function updatePublishingPage(pageUrl,properties) {

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var site = context.get_site();    
var web = context.get_web();
var pageFile = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
var pageItem = pageFile.get_listItemAllFields();
context.load(site);
context.load(pageItem);

context.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {

        for(var propName in properties) {
           var property = properties[propName]; 
           var itemValue = pageItem.get_item(propName);
           if(property.Type == "Url") {
               var pagelayoutUrl = site.get_url() + property.Value.split(',')[0].trim();
               itemValue.set_url(pagelayoutUrl);
               var pagelayoutDesc = property.Value.split(',')[1].trim();
               itemValue.set_description(pagelayoutDesc);
               pageItem.set_item(propName,itemValue);
           }

        }
        pageItem.update();
        context.load(pageItem);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
               console.log(pageItem);
            },
            function (sender, args) {
               console.log('Failed: ' + args.get_message());
            }
        );    
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log('Failed: ' + args.get_message());
    }
   );

}
```

call the following:

```
var properties = {'PublishingPageLayout' : {'Type': 'Url','Value': '/_catalogs/masterpage/ArticleLeft.aspx, Image on left'}};  //Image on Left page layout
updatePublishingPage('/news/Pages/Latest-News.aspx',properties);
```

[Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92910/setting-page-layout-using-jsom)